# How to find the centroid of a group of contours?

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image of a group of small circles. Each circle is a separate contour. I need to find the centroid of the entire group without using image filtering or morphology.

[image: Holes]

My idea was to combine all the circle contours into one giant contour, then use cv2 moments to find the centroid, but it is inaccurate. This is the code I'm using (I can successfully find each hole as a contour, so I left that code out of the snippet below:

Image after finding all hole contours:
[image]

```
# holes is a list of all hole contours
combined_conts = np.concatenate(holes)

cont_moment = cv2.moments(combined_conts)
cX = int(cont_moment["m10"] / cont_moment["m00"])
cY = int(cont_moment["m01"] / cont_moment["m00"])
```

I would expect the cX and cY coordinates to be near the center of the group of holes, but they aren't even close (they're close to the top right corner of the group instead). I suspect cv2.moments is not a fan of the way the contours are combined? Is there a better way to combine contours into one?

This is what the image looks like when the holes are combined into one contour:
[image]

Comment: Can't you find the center of each contour, and then just average the Xs and Ys?

Comment: Almost, you probably also need to weight the per contour centroid averaging by the number of pixels in each contour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an easy way to get the centroid in Python/OpenCV.  Just get the centroid from the thresholded (binary) image. Zero valued pixels (black) do not contribute to the moments.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('holes.png')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# get centroid
M = cv2.moments(thresh)
cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])       
print('cx:', cx, 'cy:', cy)

# draw centroid
result = img.copy()
x = int(cx)
y = int(cy)
r = 1
cv2.circle(result, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 255), 2)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('holes_centroid.png', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Centroid:

```
cx: 101 cy: 245
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("path/to/your/image.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]  # Adjust the threshold value as needed

nonzero = cv2.findNonZero(thresh)

centroid = np.mean(nonzero, axis=0)
centroid_x = int(centroid[0][0])
centroid_y = int(centroid[0][1])

print("Centroid coordinates:", (centroid_x, centroid_y))
```

Comment: This is excellent. I would assume cv2.moments uses the same type of method for finding the centroid, but this is even shorter and sweeter.